# Align background image relatively to other background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My template is based on the Twitter Bootstrap so is responsive.

I have two div's, the first contains the background image of an iPhone frame, the second has an image of the lock screen. I am trying to align screenbackground div on top of the iphonebackground div so that it appears that it is all one image. This way I can change what is displayed on the iPhone while the frame image is static.

My issue is that I cannot find a way to align the screenbackground div over the iphonebackground div so that even when the size of the iphonebackground div changed (when the screen is resized) the screenbackground is scaled correctly and stays aligned.

```
<div class="iphonebackground">
  <div class="screenbackground"></div>
</div>

.iphonebackground {
    background-image:url("../img/iphone-frame.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    height:576px;
}

.screenbackground {
    background-image:url("../img/iphone-background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height:50%;
    width:66%;
    padding-right: 23%;
}
```

**EDIT: I have changed the code to as below and it is much closer but still not quite right:**

```
.iphonebackground {
    background-image:url("../img/iphone-frame.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    height:511px;
}

.screenbackground {
    background-image:url("../img/iphone-background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:60% 50%;
    height:511px;
}
```

Comment: BTW, the width works perfectly, but the height does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you create the second image of the exact same dimension of the first one but with transparent margins? Having two equal images they are resized accordingly.

```
<div class="iphonebackground">
  <div class="screenbackground"></div>
</div>

.iphonebackground, .screenbackground {
    background-image:url("http://chpwn.com/apps/iphone-frame.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:300px;
}

.screenbackground {
    background-image:url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/290586/iphone-bg.png");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/notme/zYV8x/

Comment: You sir, are a live saver +!